# Add javascript to a woocommerce page template

Tags: javascript, woocommerce-offtopic

I have the following code in my `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dc_datepicker_options' );

function dc_datepicker_options() {
if ( is_page_template( 'single-product.php' ) ) {
  $ss_url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
  wp_enqueue_script( 'datepicker-options', "{$ss_url}/js/datepicker-options.js" );
} else {
    // Returns false 
}
}
```

I'm trying to call `datepicker-options.js` only on my product pages. But it doesn't seem to be calling it.

Comment: Is your condition correct? Do you see script output in page source?

Comment: Also make sure your page template `single-product.php` is in your theme root folder. If it's in subfolder then check it like this. `is_page_template( 'subfolder/single-product.php' )`

Comment: I probably got the location of my template wrong to begin with. Using the condition `is_product()` removes that need to find the right path. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Woocommerce conditional tag for single product page

Try

```
if(is_product())
```

instead of

```
if ( is_page_template( 'single-product.php' ))
```